# Connect to mysql db in linux mint

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am writing a java app on linux mint 21.
Trying to connect to a local mysql database i get the error

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb

I installed the mysql-connector-j_8.1.0-1debian11_all.deb package i  found at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ (choosing debian linux as os) and than linked both

```
mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar 
mysql-connector-java-8.1.0.jar
```

to the reference library of my project.

The url should be correct, so is there anything else i should do?

Edit:

Also tried the "platform indipendent" jar.

Comment: Does the editor play any role here, e.g. you're using an extension to run queries from the editor and see results in a new tab? The question itself suggests you're merely trying to connect from your own Java application and, for that, you surely need to write some code to tell javac where the JAR is.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i'm not using extension, i'm doing pretty much what you see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBhBaya7tF4

Comment: The error means that the driver is not on the classpath when you run your application. Please provide a [mre] and show how you are running your application. "Installing" Java JARs like this is an uncommon practice (and isn't something that means the driver is available when you run a Java application). Also, you should not add both JARs, just add one of them (their contents is (nearly) identical).